# AngularJS directive restrict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I made some AngularJS directives in the past week and they all work but this one just won't work and I don't know what I am doing wrong..

This is the directive I'm talking about:

```
app.directive('idleCheck', [function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'I',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          ifvisible.setIdleDuration(5);
          ifvisible.on("idle", function () {
              var div = document.getElementById('fullscreenWrap');
              div.style.cursor = 'none';
              stream.pause();
          });

          ifvisible.on("wakeup", function () {
              var div = document.getElementById('fullscreenWrap');
              div.style.cursor = 'auto';
              stream.resume();
          });
      }
  }
}]);
```

This is my HTML code where I call the directive:

```
<div id="fullscreenWrap" idle-check>
  ...
</div>
```

Do you see anything wrong in the code ?
Or do you know why it isn't working ?

Comment: change restrict to 'A'

Comment: What exactly is the error is giving? Are all the directives declared the same? There is no `restrict: I`. There is only `A` - only matches attribute name, `E` - only matches element name, `C` - only matches class name. You can however give a combination of the three.

Comment: Directive only works with restrict type A,E and C. Change  restrict: 'I',to  restrict: 'A/C/E'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change restrict field to 'A'.

> The restrict option is typically set to:
>
> 'A' - only matches attribute name 'E' - only matches element name 'C'
>   - only matches class name These restrictions can all be combined as needed:
>
> 'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name

[Angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 2):

The `restrict` options available are: `'E'`,`'A'`,`'C'`,`'M'`

One of `EACM` restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style.

You can even use **Multiple** restrictions on same directive `restrict: 'AC'`

`If you don't restrict any, the defaults (elements and attributes) are used`.

`E` - Element name (default): `<my-directive></my-directive>`

`A` - Attribute (default): `<div my-directive="exp"></div>`

`C` - Class: `<div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>`

`M` - coMment: `<!-- directive: my-directive exp -->`

**For Example:**

`ng-if` is restricted to `'A'`. so it can be used only as attribute, you can't use as comment or element

Here's the angularjs code for ngIf

```
var ngIfDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',       // --> This means restricting to Attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what error it is actually giving your issue is most likely your directive declaration.

There is no `restrict: I`. Angular only supports three values for this:

`A` - only matches attribute name
`E` - only matches element name
`C` - only matches class name

You can but any combination of the three though to support multiple cases.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive
It states the info at the bottom of the `template expanding directive` section.